# Did something try to access my facebook?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pycharm

So I was running the basic tutorial code for google app engine Datastore introduciton:

```
import cgi
import datetime
import urllib
import webapp2

from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.api import users


class Greeting(db.Model):
    """Models an individual Guestbook entry with an author, content, and date."""
    author = db.UserProperty()
    content = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
    date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)


def guestbook_key(guestbook_name=None):
    """Constructs a datastore key for a Guestbook entity with guestbook_name."""
    return db.Key.from_path('Guestbook', guestbook_name or 'default_guestbook')


class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write('<html><body>')
        guestbook_name=self.request.get('guestbook_name')

        # Ancestor Queries, as shown here, are strongly consistent with the High
        # Replication datastore. Queries that span entity groups are eventually
        # consistent. If we omitted the ancestor from this query there would be a
        # slight chance that Greeting that had just been written would not show up
        # in a query.
        greetings = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * "
                                "FROM Greeting "
                                "WHERE ANCESTOR IS :1 "
                                "ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 10",
            guestbook_key(guestbook_name))

        for greeting in greetings:
            if greeting.author:
                self.response.out.write(
                    '<b>%s</b> wrote:' % greeting.author.nickname())
            else:
                self.response.out.write('An anonymous person wrote:')
            self.response.out.write('<blockquote>%s</blockquote>' %
                                    cgi.escape(greeting.content))

        self.response.out.write("""
          <form action="/sign?%s" method="post">
            <div><textarea name="content" rows="3" cols="60"></textarea></div>
            <div><input type="submit" value="Sign Guestbook"></div>
          </form>
          <hr>
          <form>Guestbook name: <input value="%s" name="guestbook_name">
          <input type="submit" value="switch"></form>
        </body>
      </html>""" % (urllib.urlencode({'guestbook_name': guestbook_name}),
                    cgi.escape(guestbook_name)))


class Guestbook(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        # We set the same parent key on the 'Greeting' to ensure each greeting is in
        # the same entity group. Queries across the single entity group will be
        # consistent. However, the write rate to a single entity group should
        # be limited to ~1/second.
        guestbook_name = self.request.get('guestbook_name')
        greeting = Greeting(parent=guestbook_key(guestbook_name))

        if users.get_current_user():
            greeting.author = users.get_current_user()

        greeting.content = self.request.get('content')
        greeting.put()
        self.redirect('/?' + urllib.urlencode({'guestbook_name': guestbook_name}))


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),
    ('/sign', Guestbook)],
    debug=True)
```

Within Pycharm I just press 'shift+F10' to run the above code.

I get the following logging before the site opens up at 127.0.0.1:8080:

> C:\Python27\python.exe "C:/Program
>   Files/Google/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py" .
>
> WARNING  2012-03-02 01:34:41,374 rdbms_mysqldb.py:74] The rdbms API is
>   not available because the MySQLdb library could not be loaded.
>
> INFO     2012-03-02 01:34:41,976 appengine_rpc.py:160] Server:
>   appengine.google.com
>
> INFO     2012-03-02 01:34:41,983 appcfg.py:581] Checking for updates
>   to the SDK.
>
> INFO     2012-03-02 01:34:44,369 appcfg.py:599] The SDK is up to date.
>
> WARNING  2012-03-02 01:34:44,371 datastore_file_stub.py:513] Could not
>   read datastore data from
>   c:\users\robert\appdata\local\temp\dev_appserver.datastore
>
> INFO     2012-03-02 01:34:46,295 dev_appserver_multiprocess.py:650]
>   Running application dev~helloworld on port 8080: http://localhost:8080
>
> INFO     2012-03-02 01:34:46,296 dev_appserver_multiprocess.py:652]
>   Admin console is available at: http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin
>
> WARNING  2012-03-02 01:34:47,480 py_zipimport.py:139] Can't open
>   zipfile C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyfacebook-1.0a2-py2.7.egg:
>   IOError: [Errno 13] file not accessible:
>   'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyfacebook-1.0a2-py2.7.egg'
>
> INFO     2012-03-02 01:34:49,108 datastore_stub_index.py:257] Updating
>   C:\Users\Robert\PycharmProjects\helloworld\index.yaml
>
> INFO     2012-03-02 01:34:49,148 dev_appserver.py:2865] "GET /
>   HTTP/1.1" 200 -
>
> INFO     2012-03-02 01:34:49,315 dev_appserver.py:2865] "GET
>   /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -

Note the log has the line:

**WARNING  2012-03-02 01:34:47,480 py_zipimport.py:139] Can't open zipfile C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyfacebook-1.0a2-py2.7.egg: IOError: [Errno 13] file not accessible: 'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyfacebook-1.0a2-py2.7.egg'**

I'm sure there is a reasonable, logical explanation for this, anyone know?

Comment: yes pyfacebook-1.0a2-py2.7.egg is in that directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know for sure, but it "smells" like a path / installation conflict.  Perhaps App Engine is finding the package in a spot where it can't access it (in another python installation, perhaps?). If you can import the package from the interactive python shell, then the file has the right permissions; in that case, check for multiple installations / install paths.  In my case, something was installed in the "system" python but not the one App Engine was using.